# Maximum item length in Android listview?

Tags: java, android, mobile

In an Android `ListView`, is there a maximum length that a node in the `ListView` can handle?

I am inflating an XML-file into a `ListView`, and in certain cases, the data coming into it may be rather large...

I could perhaps truncate the data and allow the user to click on the item and bring up the full text in a separate view, but what is the max length it can handle?

Comment: Yes sir, and for bonus points (even though they dont exist), what happens in the app if this is surpassed? Some sort of overflow error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `ListView` is populated in the memory of the device. In your `ListAdapter`-class you specify the input for the list.

I can only guess but I think, for one item, it can print as much as a String can hold. Depending on how many full Strings can be placed in the Memory of your Device/Emulator, you'll get some kind of Overflow I guess.

But a `ListView` is meant to show a lot of short data and redirect to the full data (like you said with the extra Activity). Also I don't think this will look good at all.

Comment: Right, I figured I'd have to go with a truncated/short string which "zooms" to full text via a click. I was just curious if there was some set value that would "break" the object. Thanks for the input!!

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, there is no hard limit for maximum text lenght in ListView. But you are limited by device resources (memory, cpu, etc.).

From UX point of view, it is not good idea to place long text in ListView. Make your users happy and split it to list=>detail.